# How to insert 2 input fields using swal(in sweetAlert) in the onclick Function?

Tags: jquery, html, sweetalert

I tried to research on the internet and I saw that he/she make an html inside the swal then i decided to copy the codes and put it inside the onclick function. Whenever i clicked it, the swal is there but there's no input fields. The question is what is the cause why the input fields is not appearing?

```
<a id = "a" onclick = "divFunction()">Forgot Password</a>
```

**My script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function divFunction(){
    //Some code
    swal({
    title: 'Multiple inputs',
    html: true,
    text: '<h2>Login details for waybill generation</h2>'+
    '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input" autofocus placeholder="User ID">' +
    '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Password">',
     preConfirm: function() {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       if (result) {
        resolve([
          $('#swal-input1').val(),
          $('#swal-input2').val()
        ]);
       }
      });
     }
     }).then(function(result) {
    swal(JSON.stringify(result));
    })
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue, check how i solved:

```
var htmlContent = document.createElement("div");
    htmlContent.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"field1\" class=\"someclass\" placeholder=\"sometext\" name=\"field1\" autocomplete=\"off\"> <input type=\"text\" id=\"field2\" class=\"someclass\" placeholder=\"sometext2\" name=\"field2\" autocomplete=\"off\">";
    swal(msg, {
        content: htmlContent,
        buttons: ["No", "Yes"]
    }).then((willDelete) =>{
        if (willDelete) {
            //actions if yes
        }
    });
```